# How does the electron configuration of platinum relate to its stability?

Tags: electronic-configuration, metal, periodic-trends, metallurgy, relativistic

Does platinum's electron configuration, [Xe] 4f14 5d9 6s1, influence its reactivity and stability? Is the electron configuration the primary contributing factor to platinum's relative inertness?

This seems odd to me that platinum is very inert. It seems like pulling off that 6s1 electron should not be difficult as compared to other metals.

Comment: It has to do with the relativistic effect that contracts the orbit of the 6s electron.  The relativistic effect is explained in [this earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/why-is-gold-golden/16637#16637).

Comment: Platinum isn't unreactive. It is resistant to some specific reactions (oxidation or tarnishing) but is a very good catalyst for others (e.g. methanol oxidation, oxidation of residual hydrocarbons in catalytic converters, ammonia oxidation...). And it has a rich chemistry.