# Why are certain substances clear/invisible? Can we create invisible objects?

Tags: color, optical-properties, electromagnetic-radiation

This is more so a question of how light interacts with matter. For example, why are substances like oxygen generally invisible? If the light hitting the molecules were absorbed, it would appear black, right?

Also, could we create invisible materials?

Comment: Well, that just means that oxygen does not absorb in the visible region of the spectrum.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/why-is-gold-golden

Comment: Mankind has done so since ancient times. Glass is effectively invisible, hence why silly insects keep flying against it.

Comment: Invisible to all wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation, and all sorts of particle beams? - No. // Invisible to a certain  range of the electromagnetic spectrum (like human eye range)? - Yes.